# Django Restful framework post to create foreign key if not already exists

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

```
class ModelA(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    code = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='')

class ModelB(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    code = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='')

class ModelC(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    modelA = models.ForeignKey(ModelA, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    modelB = models.ForeignKey(ModelB, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

These are the models.

```
class ModelASerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = ModelA
        fields = "__all__"

class ModelBSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = ModelB
        fields = "__all__"

class ModelC(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    modelA = ModelASerializer()
    modelB = ModelBSerializer()
    class Meta:
        model = ModelC
        fields = "__all__"
```

These are my serializers.

Right now I have no problem with a GET request. What I want to achieve is that when I do a post request for ModelC and if ModelA and ModelB do not already exist then create them. Right now I am able to do post with existing modelA and modelB by removing the nested serializer.

Thanks for everyone's help.

Comment: I don't have time to write a formal answer right now, but check out http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#writable-nested-serializers